# How to using Math.round(easeOut(time...) in after affects?

Tags: animation, after-effects

I have a shape layer and I want to animate position x using this expression

```
x=clamp(thisComp.layer("Control Values").effect("Value Bar 1")("Slider"),0,100);
Math.round(easeOut(time,inPoint+0.53,inPoint+1.8, 0, x))
[x, value[0]]
```

but he shows "expression result must be of dimension 2. not 1"

[image]

where is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your set up with Shape Layer + Control Values layer with a slider and I'm getting [slightly different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YenGc.png).

I think your code is giving you errors as it is missing semi-colons on 2nd and 3d line and AE does not know when to stop working on 1 line and move to next one? There must be a term for it :)

Here is the code that works for me without any errors:

```
x=clamp(thisComp.layer("Control Values")("Effects")("Values Bar 1")("Slider"),0,100);

Math.round(easeOut(time,inPoint+0.53,inPoint+1.8, 0, x));

[x, value[0]];
```

I would clean it up a little bit to make it more readable. Also, you should make a variable for *Math.round* function, since you want to use it to affect position x? Also I changed *value[0]* to *value[1]* - otherwise, your Position y is referring to Position X original value. You can change it, but it is a little bit counterintuitive - you move your layer left/right, so it goes up/down - value[1] fixes this.

```
valuesBar = thisComp.layer("Control Values")("Effects")("Values Bar 1")("Slider");

x=clamp(valuesBar, 0,100);

x2 = Math.round(easeOut(time,inPoint+0.53,inPoint+1.8, 0, x));

[x2, value[1]];
```